# notation of a real coordinate system of n dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, coordinate-systems

I observe that books write a bold faced R,

But the professors write R preceded by a bar. Is that I, denoting infinitism?
I am not sure if it is I, its more of a vertical bar. Is it universal, or incidentally I am coming across only such professors?

|R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard convention for writing bold face in mediums that aren't amenable to heavy/thick strokes is to instead double some of the lines in a character; e.g. with the diagonal line in $\mathbb{Z}$.

This is called "blackboard bold".

(although since so much math is done on blackboards, $\mathbb{R}$ has partially taken over from $\mathbf{R}$ as the standard notation for the reals)

Comment: And here I thought the regular bold font was some modern(ish) French thing, like using outward facing brackets in interval notation. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

That bar is used so that alphabet R becomes free for further usage.$\mathbb{R}$ denotes set of real number and R is simple alphabet which can be used for any purpose. But if we denote R as set of real number then alphabet R gets freezed for further usage

Comment: Well, it's not so much |R as it is $\Bbb R$... But I agree with the answer in principle :)

Comment: yeah i meant that only. whats syntax for it

Comment: The "long" and proper way is to use the command `\mathbb{R}` (in math mode, so between dollar signs) to use the BlackBoard Bold font. But `\Bbb{R}` also works, although it's probably deprecated, if it's even an option in (La)TeX.